# Unreachable item (?) in Old Akelarre

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm pretty far into the game (but haven't triggered NG+), and on a whim I walked back from Majula to Old Akelarre, and inside the first oval-shaped room, where the 6 goblins ambush you, I can see, up on the second level, to the left as you enter the room, a glowing spinning thing.   It looks much the way things look when another player character drops something for you to pick up.

I can't find any reference to this item anywhere, much less any way to get up there to get it.  Has anybody else seen this, and has anybody gotten it?    I need it.   It taunts me.

EDIT:   Screenshot of the item in question

[image]

Comment: I watched a video where the room is thoroughly shown, but I couldn't see any items there. Maybe you have mistaken an enemy as item?

Answer (score 1):

This item is a little tricky to get to. You have to do a running jump off the stairs to get to it.

It might take a few tries, but it's as straightforward as it sounds. Run up the stairs, then turn 90 degrees toward the shelf, and jump.

After doing a bit more research, there is nothing more in the first room, other than what you can find in the ground floor. Whatever it is you're seeing, it's not an item.

Comment: This isn't in the room with the stairs.   It's in the room where the petrified woman is originally blocking the pull-switch to open the door.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: @TabAlleman yeah, that's not an item. Not exactly sure what it is, it might be a light or something.